# Printing specific user input in java

Tags: java, string, input, integer, compare

I have to design a program that gets 3 user-inputs in the form:

```
Name1   (any number of spaces)  age1
Name2   (any number of spaces)  age3
Name3   (any number of spaces)  age3
```

Then print line which has the highest age (suppose Name3 age3 had the highest age I'd print his line).

My Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RankAge{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter 3 different names and the age of each person respectively:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n1 = sc.nextLine();
    String n2 = sc.nextLine();
    String n3 = sc.nextLine();

    }
}
```

I know how to scan the user-inputs, but i don't know how to do a comparison of the number within the acquired string to print a specific one (also since there can be any number of spaces it seems even more complicated to me).

Comment: You can split the string on any number of spaces using `n1.split("\\s+")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` to get the person's age:

```
String age = "Jon       57".split("\\s+")[1]; // contains "57"
```

You can then use `Integer.parseInt(age)` to get the person's age, as a number.

---

If you need to allow the user to input a name with spaces, you can adjust the number in square brackets (`[]`). For example, `[2]` would require the user to input a first name and last name.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to do it with frenchDolphin's suggestion. This is the code i used (it's quite beginner friendly):

```
import java.util.*;
public class RankAge{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter 3 different names and the age of each person respectively:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n1 = sc.nextLine();
    String a1 = n1.split("\\s+")[1];
    String n2 = sc.nextLine();
    String a2 = n2.split("\\s+")[1];
    String n3 = sc.nextLine();
    String a3 = n3.split("\\s+")[1];

    if(Integer.parseInt(a1) > Integer.parseInt(a2)){
    } if(Integer.parseInt(a1) > Integer.parseInt(a3)){
            System.out.println(n1);
    }else if(Integer.parseInt(a2) > Integer.parseInt(a3)){
        System.out.println(n2);
    }else{
        System.out.println(n3);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 because at first look it seemed very simple but when I started implementing the complexities started showing up. Here is the complete solution for your problem,

```
import java.util.*;

public class RankAge {

   public static void main(String s[]){
        System.out.println("Enter 3 different names and the age of each person respectively:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n[] = new String[3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            n[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        int age[] = new int[3];

        age[0] = Integer.parseInt(n[0].split("\\s+")[1]);
        age[1] = Integer.parseInt(n[1].split("\\s+")[1]);
        age[2] = Integer.parseInt(n[2].split("\\s+")[1]);
        int ageTemp[] = age;
        for(int i=0;i<age.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<age.length;j++){
                int tempAge = 0;
                String tempN = "";
                if(age[i]<ageTemp[j]){
                    tempAge = age[i];
                    tempN = n[i];
                    age[i] = age[j];
                    n[i] = n[j];
                    age[j] = tempAge;
                    n[j] = tempN;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            System.out.println(n[i]);
        }

   }

}
```